# Using Search and Replace with VBA/Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Got an annoying Excel/VBA issue that I can't seem to get around - would appreciate any help.

I have a formula in a spreadsheet that says something along the lines of if the cell to its left =1, then the cell itself =on, and if not, ="off".
Is it possible to write some VBA search and replace code that turns "off" to "totally_off" when run?

At the moment it just seems to be editing the formula itself, while I really want it to delete everything in that cell and just replace it with the phrase "totally_off"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you could do a search and replace looking for `*off*` and replacing with `totally off`.

Comment: actually, the problem is that this will replace any cell with off in the formula, I only want to alter the ones where these cells have met the criteria to be outputting "off"

Comment: Thanks, I get the problem now.

Comment: You could still do as @chuff suggested. Just click the "Match Entire Cell Contents Option" before you do the Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work. Just replace the range `B1:B10` with the range that the formulas you want to change are in. The procedure tests the value of the cell immediately to the left of the cells in the formula. If the value is zero, it replaces the formula with the "totally off".

```
Sub totally_off()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Variant
    Set rng = Range("B1:B10")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 0 Then
            cell.Value = "totally off"
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Here's a non-VBA, non-search and replace alternative.

- Set up a filter on the formula column with `Sort and Filter` / `Filter` on the Home ribbon.
- Select "off" from the drop-down menu on the column.
- Type "totally off" in the first cell of the filtered column and copy it down to the bottom of the column.
- Then remove the filter. The formulas evaluating to "on" will remain intact.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA - simply use an AutoFilter:

- Select the column with the on/off formula
- Apply an AutoFilter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>
- Filter for  `off`
- Again, select all values
- Simply type in your replacement value `totally_off`into the formula bar - but press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Done!